# javascript string replace regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Syntax error.

```
var str = "D:\Imaging\EMail\31844529039.pdf";
str = str.replace(/\/g, "\\");
alert(str);
```

Please help
required output is `D:\\ImagingEMail\\31844529039.pdf`

Comment: This one is asked multiple times before. Like http://stackoverflow.com/q/14624295/508702 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8684975/508702

Comment: you can see out put not getting ... please see alert it alert D:ImagingEMail31844529039.pdf instead of D:\\Imaging\\EMail\\31844529039.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The `\` is an escaping sign both in string literals and in regex literals, so you must escape it. Use

```
var str = "D:\\Imaging\\EMail\\31844529039.pdf";
str = str.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```

This builds this string :

```
D:\\Imaging\\EMail\\31844529039.pdf
```

Special characters in String literals are described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals).

Special characters in regular expression literals are described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: You put two backslash in the string literal, and there's only one in the resulting string.

Comment: you can see out put not getting ... please see alert it alert D:ImagingEMail31844529039.pdf instead of D:\\Imaging\\EMail\\31844529039.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
str = str .replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```