# HTML escapes string with Backslashes

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to `Javascript` coding. The current task I am working on is creating HTML Documents from a text document.In a particular case, I have a complex string (alphanumeric string with backslashes). I need the HTML to print it the way the text is present. 
However, the HTML created escapes all backslashes.

**Input Text:**

```
3583859858.8200040004xxxx\00\0200040004\t0\t194.3\t39874\t7975\t90\t62\t0.1\t194.3\t200\t35.00\t35.00\t35.00\t194\t2.1\t12541\t12650\t13468\t13421\t13481\t13932\t35.00\t35.00\n
```

**Output in HTML:**

```
3583859858.8200040004xxxx0040004 0t194.3 39874 7975 90 62 0.1 194.3 200 35.00 35.00 35.00t194 2.1   12541 12650 13468 13421 13481 13932 35.00 35.00
```

I tried below solutions to other relevant questions but it did not work

[How to escape backslash in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866461/how-to-escape-backslash-in-javascript)

[Backslashes - Regular Expression - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769964/backslashes-regular-expression-javascript)

[How can I replace a backslash with a double backslash using RegExp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684975/how-can-i-replace-a-backslash-with-a-double-backslash-using-regexp)

Request help from seniors here

Comment: for escaping backslash, add another backslash after it. like this \\

Comment: The text file is generated at runtime . Need to replace the backSlash before the HTML is created

Comment: have you tried <pre>?

Comment: On reading through similar questions in stack overflow, the concerned text becomes an Octal Escape sequence.  Need to handle this sequence

Answer (score 1):

One Solution is to use JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY

Checkout This Demo

```js
var string = '3583859858.8200040004xxxx\00\0200040004\t0\t194.3\t39874\t7975\t90\t62\t0.1\t194.3\t200\t35.00\t35.00\t35.00\t194\t2.1\t12541\t12650\t13468\t13421\t13481\t13932\t35.00\t35.00\n';

$("#result").html(string);

// IF THIS IS NOT WORKING THEN TRY THIS 

var htmlString = string.split("\\");
$("#resultHtml").html(htmlString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<br>
<div id="resultHtml"></div>

<!-- Third Solution ** &#160; FOR \t AND &#10; FOR \n-->
<div>3583859858.8200040004xxxx\00\0200040004&#160;0&#160;194.3&#160;39874&#160;7975&#160;90&#160;62&#160;0.1&#160;194.3&#160;200&#160;35.00&#160;35.00&#160;35.00&#160;194&#160;2.1&#160;12541&#160;12650&#160;13468&#160;13421&#160;13481&#160;13932&#160;35.00&#160;35.00&#10;</div>
```

This Might Be Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use html character instead. Replace all backslashes with

```
&#92;
```

---

Example

```html
<span>&#92;t0&#92;t194.3&#92;t39874</span>
```